# ¿Cómo evitar que machaque la estructura html con javascript,utilizando DOM?

Tags: javascript, html, css, html5, dom

Como veis estoy solucionando una cuestión esta tarde, que me trae de cabeza, la idea es que no machaque el texto que ya tiene el documento html, para ello tengo lo siguiente.

Perdonar la demora, pero lo conseguí unos dias después, era bastante sencillo, había que recorrer los nodos añadiendo el titulo al principio de la cabecera.

```js
/* 4. Recorre los artículos y añade al inicio de la cabecera el 
número de noticia (1 - Cualquier titulo... ) */

var article0 = document.getElementsByTagName("article")[0];
article0.id = "primerArticulo";

var parrafo = document.getElementById('primerArticulo');
var newElement = document.createElement('h1');
newElement.textContent = "1 - Cualquier titulo...";
primerArticulo.insertBefore(newElement,primerArticulo.children[0]);
```

```html
     <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html lang="en">
        <head>
            <meta charset="UTF-8">
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
            
            <title>Una web cualquiera</title>
            </head>
        <body>
            <h1 id="titulo">DOM</h1>
            <section id="noticias">
                <div class="fila">
                    <article>
                        <div>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged</div>
                        <div class="cuerpo">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged</div>
                    </article>
                    </div>
                </section>
        </body>
        </html>
```

Comment: ¿Podrías aclarar un poco cuál sería el resultado esperado? ¿Al principio de dónde, del primer div dentro del article? ¿El div .cuerpo se debe quedar igual?

Comment: Hola @sema, la idea era poner el titulo al principio de la cabecera del articulo, ya modifiqué la pregunta con la solución un saludo !